# Cannot scrape top selling products from shopee.com

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I was trying to scrape the name, category, and numbers sold of the top products from an Indonesian eCommerce website https://shopee.co.id/top_products, using python with requests and BeautifulSoup package. But I'm having a lot of trouble. Here's my first attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.961206468.1594951946; _med=refer; _fbp=fb.2.1594951949275.1940955365; SPC_IA=-1; SPC_F=y1evilme0ImdfEmNWEc08bul3d8toc33; REC_T_ID=fab983c8-c7d2-11ea-a977-ccbbfe23657a; SPC_SI=uv1y64sfvhx3w6dir503ixw89ve2ixt4; _gid=GA1.3.413262278.1594951963; SPC_U=286107140; SPC_EC=GwoQmu7TiknULYXKODlEi5vEgjawyqNcpIWQjoxjQEW2yJ3H/jsB1Pw9iCgGRGYFfAkT/Ej00ruDcf7DHjg4eNGWbCG+0uXcKb7bqLDcn+A2hEl1XMtj1FCCIES7k17xoVdYW1tGg0qaXnSz0/Uf3iaEIIk7Q9rqsnT+COWVg8Y=; csrftoken=5MdKKnZH5boQXpaAza1kOVLRFBjx1eij; welcomePkgShown=true; _ga=GA1.1.1693450966.1594951955; _dc_gtm_UA-61904553-8=1; REC_MD_30_2002454304=1595153616; _ga_SW6D8G0HXK=GS1.1.1595152099.14.1.1595153019.0; REC_MD_41_1000044=1595153318_0_50_0_49; SPC_R_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="; SPC_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_R_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="'
}

shopee_url = 'https://shopee.co.id/top_products'

response = requests.get(shopee_url, headers=headers)
response.json()
```

But it will raise the "JSONDecodeError", which I think is because what I have scraped looks like this: view-source:https://shopee.co.id/top_products. Here's my second attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.961206468.1594951946; _med=refer; _fbp=fb.2.1594951949275.1940955365; SPC_IA=-1; SPC_F=y1evilme0ImdfEmNWEc08bul3d8toc33; REC_T_ID=fab983c8-c7d2-11ea-a977-ccbbfe23657a; SPC_SI=uv1y64sfvhx3w6dir503ixw89ve2ixt4; _gid=GA1.3.413262278.1594951963; SPC_U=286107140; SPC_EC=GwoQmu7TiknULYXKODlEi5vEgjawyqNcpIWQjoxjQEW2yJ3H/jsB1Pw9iCgGRGYFfAkT/Ej00ruDcf7DHjg4eNGWbCG+0uXcKb7bqLDcn+A2hEl1XMtj1FCCIES7k17xoVdYW1tGg0qaXnSz0/Uf3iaEIIk7Q9rqsnT+COWVg8Y=; csrftoken=5MdKKnZH5boQXpaAza1kOVLRFBjx1eij; welcomePkgShown=true; _ga=GA1.1.1693450966.1594951955; _dc_gtm_UA-61904553-8=1; REC_MD_30_2002454304=1595153616; _ga_SW6D8G0HXK=GS1.1.1595152099.14.1.1595153019.0; REC_MD_41_1000044=1595153318_0_50_0_49; SPC_R_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="; SPC_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_R_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="'
}

shopee_url = 'https://shopee.co.id/top_products'
response = requests.get(shopee_url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")

products = soup.select("._3S8sOC _2QfAXF")
print(type(products))
print(products)
```

But this would return an empty list, and I couldn't figure out why. Thanks for reading this far! I haven't encountered these problems in my earlier web crawler exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see the network calls made by the website to load the content, the content is loaded by a javascript call. The following script gives all the data for all different tabs on the website such as Kouta Data Internet, Hijab Instan etc....

[image]

```
import requests, json

res = requests.get("https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/recommend/recommend?bundle=top_sold_product_microsite&limit=20&offset=0")

data_json = res.json()

with open("data.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data_json,f)
```

The above script will save the data to a json file. Sample output of the data

```
{"data": {"update_time": 1595183508, "version": "1595183688", "sections": [{"total": 20, "key": "tspmicrosite_sec", "index": [{"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_65"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_3693"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_2"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_19"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_75"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_4040"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_877"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_15"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_10"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_7"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_722"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_285"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_20"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_66"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_5831"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_18"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_16"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_13"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_34"}, {"data_type": "top_product", "key": "ID_V2L0_1493"}], "data": {"item": null, "keyword": null, "ads": null, "top_product": [{"info": "QUE:PTCPB,SLT:tspmicrosite_slot_00,TFS:tspmicrosite_slot_00_ID,SEC:tspmicrosite_sec_00,BND:top_sold_product_microsite,EPT:top_sold_product_microsite", "count": 2296973, "data_type": "top_product", "name": "Kuota Data Internet", "label": "ID_V2L0_65", "key": "ID_V2L0_65", "images": ["5c2b241a45c93374c154f0ef47feeb32", "8c650894988ea89258dc57604938ba9b", "b0b48c0e010c0626f9cdcecef7ba33d5"], "list": {"total": 40, "key": "ID_V2L0_65", "index": [{"data_type": "item_lite", "key": "item::122997341:2405999610"}, {"data_type": "item_lite", "key": "item::157202162:2813092958"}, {"data_type": "item_lite", "key": "item::172223406:7301485432"}, {"data_type": "item_lite", "key": "item::172223406:5801486070"}, {"data_type": "item_lite", "key": "item::57561999:1771712886"}, {"data_type": "item_lite", "key": "item::12216119:2020087641"}, {"data_type": "item_lite", "key": "item::172223406:5101486536"}, {"data_type": "item_lite", "key": "item::172223406:3810851792"}, {"data_type": "item_lite", "key": "item::6343942:61264134"}, {"data_type": "item_lite", "key": 
...
...
```

Comment: Where do you get the "https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/recommend/recommend?bundle=top_sold_product_microsite&limit=20&offset=0"? I scoured the network area in the Inspect window, but could not find it.

Comment: I have upvoted already! But couldn't be displayed since it's my first question and I don't have enough reputation. But thank you so much! And I will accept the answer.  Be appreciated if you can explain why choose the 'recommend' part. 

Comment: @LeonardLee I have upvoted the question. now you can upvote

Comment: Upvoted! But I'm still confused about why choosing the 'recommend' part in the Network.

Comment: That is the part where the website asks for the information. Think of it as a backend API only for information